# FragmentTransaction.replace() fade-in transition shows "ghost" fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions

You can download my entire project to try and debug. Here is a repo of my entire code: https://bitbucket.org/lexic92/studio48/

---

**I have a "ghost fragment" appearing in the transition when I try to replace a blank fragment with a blank fragment.**

**How to recreate the problem:**
I have a navigation drawer and when I click on an item, it opens a fragment that fills the whole screen.

Navigation Drawer:

- Button 1 - Fragment with text
- Button 2 - Fragment that is empty

  1. When I open the app, it starts out with the fragment with text.  Then, I open the Navigation Drawer and click Button 2. **Transition is bad**, and turns into a blank screen for a split second, then switches back to the fading text, until it becomes a blank screen.
  2. If I open the Navigation Drawer and click on Button 2 *again*, it fades from the full text to the blank screen.  So, **for one split-second, it shows the fragment with text when it is not supposed to.** I ran through my app on debug mode, step by step, to slow it down and verify that this behavior actually happened.
  3. If I open the Navigation Drawer and click on Button 2 *again* for the third time, it **correctly does not show any animations because it is fading to the same screen.**

Does anyone know why this happens? Do you think it has anything to do with the navigation drawer?

**Here is a repo of my entire code:** https://bitbucket.org/lexic92/studio48/

Here are some code excerpts:

**SongDetailActivity.java:**

```
      @Override
      public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        //OPEN THE BLANK SCREEN
        if(position == 1) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    //.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                    .replace(R.id.songlist_detail_container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1, mSongId))
                    .commit();
        }
        //OPEN THE SCREEN WITH TEXT
        else {
            SongDetailFragment sdf = new SongDetailFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(SongDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, mSongId);
            sdf.setArguments(args);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    //.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                    .replace(R.id.songlist_detail_container, sdf)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

The same problem happens when I comment out the 2 lines that say ".setTransition" and un-comment the 2 lines that say ".setCustomAnimations". Here are the custom animations:

**res/anim/fade_out.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**res/anim/fade_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
           android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

How can I get it to transition smoothly without the "ghost" fragment showing up?

**Specs:** I am running with android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity, minSdkVersion == 15, and targetSdkVersion == 21, on a Google Nexus 5 physical device (not an emulator).

**My guesses of the answer:**

This website seems to give me a hint: http://gotoanswer.com/?q=Android+Animation+within+a+Fragment+not+working

> Personally for me this is a bug with the zPosition for Fragment
>   animations.
>
> What you see is the new fragment "appearing" this is because the new
>   fragment is attached underneath the current one.
>
> So when trying to animate a fragment 'Over the top' of an existing
>   fragment, it appears like nothing is happening then the new one just
>   'appears'.
>
> I have tried many work arounds, playing with zPosition (only affects
>   windows not layouts, so no effect to fragments), onAnimationCreate()
>   bringing the root layout to front or even on animation start and
>   stop... seems to do nothing.
>
> So at this point in time without writing a complete custom animation
>   for fragment transitions, they are a bit buggy at the moment.
>
> You may have to play with. .add(Fragment) wait for it to be added,
>   then call .remove(Fragment) removing the old fragment, that way the
>   new fragment is physically placed on top of the existing fragment.

I did notice that **this code** was being called upon instantiation of SongDetailActivity.java, even without me clicking on the navigation drawer:

```
//OPEN THE SCREEN WITH TEXT
            else {
                SongDetailFragment sdf = new SongDetailFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString(SongDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, mSongId);
                sdf.setArguments(args);
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        //.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out)
                        .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                        .replace(R.id.songlist_detail_container, sdf)
                        .commit();
            }
```

Maybe the current fragment is fading out to this "underlying" fragment, as the quotation suggests, before fading in to the new fragment?

### What I ended up doing

*Note: I am not putting this as an answer because it does not technically answer my question, but it's the best back-up-plan solution I can come up with.*

I tried seeing if the problem was solved when there was *no* animation. The "ghost fragment" didn't show up, but I *did* notice that it took a split second to load the fragment, which looked jarring and ugly. I wanted a silky smooth app, and if it isn't smooth when there was *no* animation, then it will probably be hopeless even if I *did* fix the ghost fragment bug. I learned that fragments are just buggy (see [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-working-with-androids-child-fragment-manager-and-custom-transitions/)).

I decided to hide and show views instead. Here is my new code:

**SongDetailActivity.java**

```
//---------- NAVIGATION DRAWER -------------
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

        //HOME
        if (position == 0) {

        }
        //LYRICS
        else if(position == 1) {
            findViewById(R.id.lyrics).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.info).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
        //INFO
        else if(position == 2) {
            findViewById(R.id.info).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.lyrics).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
```

I also copied and pasted the layouts for the 2 fragments (the empty one and the one with lots of text) into the same layout, as children of a FrameLayout parent:

**fragment_songlist_detail.xml:**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f8bbd0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyrics"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    ...
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

It works fine, but I just don't know how to make it fade in and fade out. But that is a question for a separate stack overflow question. If anyone solves the ghost fragment mystery, I'm very interested to know the answer. But I decided I'm not going to waste my time trying to figure it out right now, especially when fragments' transitions have proven to be buggy in the past (like in that [article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-working-with-androids-child-fragment-manager-and-custom-transitions/)).

Comment: It's not a solution for your question but you can try "FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN"

Comment: @savepopulation I just tried it, and it has the same problem, only the animation looks different.

Comment: @RockLee Do you still have this problem ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem..

Comment: No I have not. I'm surprised it's still a problem after 3 years- I hoped Android would have fixed it. :\

Answer (score 0):

do this for all your Transaction calls

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.
                            TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE).remove(current_fragment).commit();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.songlist_detail_container, PlaceholderFragment.
                           newInstance(position + 1, mSongId)).commit();
```

see if it helps. The idea is to first commit a remove,after commit an addition. you can also go for `FragmentManager.hide(Fragment);`